# Pickadate/Pickatime datetimepicker - selected value keeps changing back to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickadate

I have two time pickers, first one is for a 'from' time and the second is a 'to' time.
What I was trying to achieve was that when the 'from' time was picked, the 'to' time would then disable all times before the 'from' time and if the 'to' time was before the newly selected 'from' time, it would update the 'to' time 15 minutes after the 'from' time.

Changing the value of the select and also disabling the times work perfectly when independent of each other, but when using them together, the time always reverts back to 1:30PM which looks like the median value in the select.

I ended up figuring this out and posted the answer below for anyone else that comes across this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up working out that it was the `disable` function that was causing the issue, I was originally setting the `disable` times before checking if the current value of the `to` time was less than then `from` time.

When disabling times, `pickatime` will reset the currently set time to the median value, which for me was 1:30PM.

All I needed to do was increment the `to` time by 15 minutes in relation to the new `from` time before disabling any times.

My code that ended up fixing the problem

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker' + COUNT + '1' + ' input').on('change', function()
        {
            var time = jQuery(this).pickatime('picker').get('select'),
                hour = time.hour,
                minute = time.mins,
                count = jQuery(this).data('count'),

            picker = jQuery('#datetimepicker' + count + '2' + ' input').pickatime('picker');
            picker.set('enable', true);

            if (picker.get('value') != '')
            {
                if (picker.get('select').time <= time.time)
                {
                    picker.set('select', time.time + 15);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                picker.set('select', time.time + 15);
            }

            picker.set('disable',[{from: [7, 0], to: [hour, minute]}]);

            picker.render;
        });
```

Hope this saves anyone else dealing with this some time. :)